# EaselJS line draw with unnecessary multiple dots issues

Tags: createjs, easeljs

While drawing a line on canvas, it creates multiple dots within the line. I am using easelJS for canvas drawing. Please refer the attached screenshot.

Code for line draw is as below.

[Line with multiple dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8cf5.png)

```
scope.init = function(){
  stage = new createjs.Stage(element[0].id);
  stage.enableDOMEvents(true);
  createjs.Touch.enable(stage);
  shellWrapper = new createjs.Container();
  shellWrapper.id = mainContainerId;
  shellWrapper.hitArea = new createjs.Shape(new createjs.Graphics().f('#000').dr(0,0,cacheWidth,cacheHeight));
  shellWrapper.cache(0,0,cacheWidth,cacheHeight); // Cache it.
  stage.addChild(shellWrapper);
  drawing = new createjs.Shape();
  shellWrapper.addChild(drawing);
  stage.update();
}

scope.mouseDown = function(event) {
  oldX = event.stageX;
  oldY = event.stageY;

  shellWrapper.addEventListener('pressmove', function(evt){

    drawing.graphics.beginStroke(color)
        .setStrokeStyle(size, 'round')
        .moveTo(oldX, oldY)
        .lineTo(evt.stageX, evt.stageY);

    oldX = evt.stageX;
    oldY = evt.stageY;
    shellWrapper.updateCache(erase?'destination-out':'source-over');
    drawing.graphics.clear();
    stage.update();
  });
};
```

Comment: So what's your actual question?

Comment: Unnecessary dots appearing within a line.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because a single line has its limits rounded, so it actually look like this:

[image: green ellipse]

The rounded edge goes a little bit (depending on stroke width) out of the line boundary so it gets over the past line drawn. This line overlay causes your drawing to look like it has small circles, but it does not, and thats because you're using a semi transparent color on the stroke.

[image]

To solve the issue, make the stroke color opaque and add transparency to the whole drawing by using `myDisplayObj.alpha = 0.5;`

This way individual lines will be fully opaque in relation to each other but they will be semi transparent relative to other display objects in the scene.